# Single Form Submission Generating Multiple Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a `Google Form` that, when submitted, creates a single row in a `Google Spreadsheet` that looks something like this:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF
```

What I would like to do is to create code to generate multiple rows with a single submission that looks something like:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnE
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnF
```

I know this can be done with `Google Scripts` but I have no programming experience with that :(

Answer (score 0):

If you know Javascript you shouldn't have much trouble picking up AppScript. Check out the official documentation at the following link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

The Guides and Reference sections will prove invaluable.

Given your scenario there are a few things you'll need to do. You'll need to create a stand-alone form (a form not bound to a spreadsheet) and then create a custom function to handle form submissions which will ultimately insert data into a spreadsheet. The [Form Service reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) documents functions that will help you to accomplish this. Of course you'll need to know how to manipulate and add data to your spreadsheet. The Spreadsheet Service reference covers this information in detail.